# Не работает расширение Хрома на открытом окне с помощью window.open

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Есть плагин для браузера Chrome, есть некая веб страница с которой открывают методом window.open окно(другая веб страница, с ссылкой на тот же ресурс что и основная) и получается так, что плагин работает с текущей страницей, но не видит открытое окно. Как заставить плагин видеть дочерние окна?